# putting CURL result in a string and not STDOUT?

Tags: c, http, curl, stdout, io-redirection

I have the following curl code, which make a request to website and retrieve data from it, it works well, but I want to store my data in a string and not in the output window. Any idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the description of `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` and also this example: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int http_get_response(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t rxed, char **msg_in)
{
    char *c;

    if (asprintf(&c, "%s%.*s", *msg_in, size * rxed, buffer) == -1) {
        free(*msg_in);
        msg_in = NULL;
        return -1;
    }

    free(*msg_in);
    *msg_in = c;

    return size * rxed;
}
```

and add the following curl option in your main

```
char *msg_in = calloc(1,sizeof(char));

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, http_get_response);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &msg_in);
```

Then you will get the message in the `msg_in`

**EDIT**

do not forget to free `msg_in` when it become uselless in your program

```
free(msg_in); msg_in = NULL;
```

Comment: @Aoues Guesmi do not forget to free `msg_in` when it become uselless in your program

    `free(msg_in); msg_in = NULL;`

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL also, since your write function **appends** characters to `msg_in` you should handle the initialization case, i.e you could pre-allocate it `char *msg_in = malloc(1); *msg_in = '\0';` or treat this case within the write function itself (e.g if `msg_in` is `NULL`, allocate it and `memcpy` the bytes from input buffer).

Comment: @deltheil Indeed I forget to add that in my answer. Thank you for the remark. answer updated

Answer (score 1):

A a general (non-curl specific) method, change your standard output (path 1) (or standard error: path 2) path(s) prior to calling curl. Read the man page on `dup2` to see how to duplicate a path to a specific descriptor, and the `fdopen` function to get a `FILE *` out of it.

The idea is you first `dup` path 1 for stdout, and/or 2 for stderr, to save copies of them somewhere. You then `close` the original paths. You create a pipe (`man pipe`) and then `dup2` the second channel of the pipe to path 1 (or 2). You can now `read()` from the first channel of the pipe to get the output that was placed there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: he didn't find the macro CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER. Where is it? isn't it in curl/curl.h ?

Comment: This isn't curl in php, it's standalone curl